# Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable: Create Dictionary based on IImmutableDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, immutability

I have code where I get an IDictionary and need to return an IImmutableDictionary. No problem, I just run the extension method ToImmutableDictionary().

Elsewhere, I get an IImmutableDictionary and need to return an IDictionary. Is there a preferred way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `imutable.ToDictionary(r=> r.Key, r=> r.Value)` like:

```
Dictionary<int,int> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
IImmutableDictionary<int, int> imutable = dictionary.ToImmutableDictionary();
IDictionary<int, int> dictionary2 = imutable.ToDictionary(r=> r.Key, r=> r.Value);
```

Comment: Your code works because your "immutable" variable is an ImmutableDictionary. Declare it as IImutableDictionary and it won't work. :-S

Comment: @RickyHelgesson, check the updated code, you are right the I missed the implicit `var` usage. Just tried the above code with sample values and it works.

Comment: Ah, never used that technique before. Thanks for solving my issue and showing me this neat trick. :)